# JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory while running ./gradlew on OSX

Tags: java, android, macos, gradle

I tried running `./gradlew` from an Android project directory, but I get an error of:

> ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory:
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_11.jdk/Contents/Home
>
> Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
>   location of your Java installation.

### Things I've tried:

1. Navigated to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`. `jdk1.8.0_11.jdk` exists, but so does `jdk1.7.0_79.jdk`
2. `which java` prints out `/usr/bin/java`
3. `printenv` prints

> ...
>
> JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_11.jdk/Contents/Home
>   JDK_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_11.jdk/Contents/Home
>
> ...

4. `javac -version` prints `javac 1.8.0_11`
5. `which javac` prints `/usr/bin/javac`

Answer (score 84):

Check if /usr/libexec/java_home exists. If it does then try running

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`
```

and rerunning your gradlew build. If it works then make it permanent with

```
echo export "JAVA_HOME=\$(/usr/libexec/java_home)" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: ...and if it doesnt exist?

Answer (score 21):

For me, I got that error no matter what I tried. Deleting the JAVA_HOME var worked for me.

Comment: Yup, perfectly worked fine! I notice the gradle already init the JAVA_HOME inside project directory (in my case, i used flutter), so I deleted the JAVA_HOME in .zhrc

Answer (score 13):

If you see this message in 2021 after upgrading to [Android Studio Arctic Fox (2020.3.1) Stable](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2021/07/android-studio-arctic-fox-202031-stable.html), then the following answer should help to get yourself unblocked.

Open the "Project Structure" window from the "File" menu and you can see that the JDK location is now moved to the Gradle settings.
[image]

Now, click on the Gradle Settings link and you can see another window in which the current JDK location is specified.
[image]

Now you should edit your `~/.bashrc` OR `~/.zshrc` to update the value of JAVA_HOME env variable.

That's it!

Now run the `source ~/.bashrc` OR `source ~/.zshrc` command or restart your terminal and enjoy running the `./gradlew` command in your project.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I have added the following to my `.bash_profile` to help sort out issues such as this one.  This has the added benefit of being able to run `setjdk {version}` and switch java versions on the fly.

```
function setjdk() {
  if [ $# -ne 0 ]; then
   removeFromPath '/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home/bin'
   if [ -n "${JAVA_HOME+x}" ]; then
    removeFromPath $JAVA_HOME
   fi
   export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v $@`
   export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
  fi
}

function removeFromPath() {
  export PATH=$(echo $PATH | sed -E -e "s;:$1;;" -e "s;$1:?;;")
}

#Default JDK to Java 8
setjdk 1.8
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead form Mac os

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home"
```

Comment: This does not look like JDK location, but Java plugin for Web location

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

In macOS, the JDK installation path is`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.jdk/Contents/Home`. See [the official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/install/installed-directory-structure-jdk-and-jre.htm#JSJIG-GUID-F7178F2F-DC92-47E9-8062-CA6B2612D350).

Answer (score -1):

If anyone comes here using fish, adding the following line to `~/.config/fish/config.fish` solves the problem for me.

```
set JAVA_HOME (/usr/libexec/java_home -v (java --version | awk 'NR==1{print $2}'))
```