# React Native on Mac: The SDK directory '/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk' does not exist

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to start up the Android simulator on my High Sierra MacBook Pro. I have followed these guides:
[React Native error: "Could not determine java version from '9.0.1'."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46867399/react-native-error-could-not-determine-java-version-from-9-0-1)

[React Native android build failed. SDK location not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32634352/react-native-android-build-failed-sdk-location-not-found)

[JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory while running ./gradlew on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34326437/java-home-is-set-to-an-invalid-directory-while-running-gradlew-on-osx)

None have been helpful. I want to get a successful build with the Android simulator on my MacBook for my React Native project.

This is the current error I am getting now when I run `react-native run-android`:

> The SDK directory '/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk' does not exist

I ran an `echo $PATH` and there is nothing on the android sdk:

> /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin:/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/bin:/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/opt/node@8/bin:~/.composer/vendor/bin:/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin:/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/bin:/Users/danale/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/bin:/Users/username/.npm-global/bin:/Users/username/.rvm/bin:/Applications/DevDesktop/tools:/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.18/bin

Does this require installing Android Studio? I do not have a folder of Android inside of my `/Library` folder. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, you need to install Android Studio for that directory to be created. Open it up as if you are about to start a project. This will allow all the necessary folders and files to be downloaded to your MacBook.

Then you need to: `cd /Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin`

Then run `./sdkmanager --licenses`

This will prompt you through to accepting all the license agreements.